# UDP Port forwarding for real Android phones, NOT emulator

Tags: android, adb, portforwarding

recently I'm trying to forward a **UDP** port from a **real** Android phone over USB to my PC.

I have tried to use

```
adb forward udp:port1 udp:port2
```

But it doesn't work, ADB reported that it doesn't support UDP port forwarding.

```
C:\Users\Kenvix>adb forward udp:22222 udp:22222
adb.exe: error: cannot bind listener: unknown socket specification:udp:22222
```

How can I forward a UDP port to my computer?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the used adb forward command and the error message.

Comment: @Robert OK, I've edited. It reported adb.exe: error: cannot bind listener: unknown socket specification:udp:22222

Comment: @Robert Sorry, but I think this solution only works for Emulators, a real phone may not have such telnet port (5554 port is bound by Android Emulator instead of ADB, and we do not have IP address when a phone connected by USB cable)

Comment: That matches your use case: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/141606/how-can-i-activate-udp-forwarding-for-usb-communication-between-a-pc-and-an-andr

Comment: @Robert  Sadly, I have tried RNDIS based USB Tethering, but it is really a terrible experience especially with Windows 10. RNDIS drivers often freezes my computer even with NDIS 6.x driver ( I've asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1697144/android-usb-tethering-causes-windows10-lagging-even-with-rndis-6-x-driver) ) :(

Comment: I finally got a little stupid solution. Use third-party software like SOCAT to wrap the packet into TCP and unwrap it in another host.

Comment: Sounds like this solution: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/141977/2241 Can you ann an full answer including the socat commands for wraping/unwrapping?